# Result of square of $(\ln(x))$. [ $(\ln x)^2$ ]

Tags: logarithms

I can’t find the square of $\ln (x)$. How a logarithmic expression be a multiple of itself?

$$(\ln(x))^2=?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In it's domain, $ln$ gives some real values. Square of a logarithmic function means square of that functional value.